# (C#) Showing where to click instead of automatic clicking

Tags: c#, mouse

I have built upon a mouse movement I found, but I don't want the program to automatically click on the things, but instead, to show me where to click. How do I do this?

(Newbie, started C# and C++ some four months ago!)

edit: 
To clarify, the program is meant to click on another window, not into itself (a macro of sorts, that is why I want an option to just show, so the user can see what the program was made to do!)

Comment: You need to design a way to indicate that a control should be clicked on. This might mean wrapping each of your controls in a decorator, which highlights it in some way. There's nothing built-in that I know of, so the answer is "write code which makes the application show you where to click"...

Comment: I see, thank you. I have not learned how to do those things you mentioned, yet, but I'll look into it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using WinForms, here's a quick example.  The "target" in this case happens to be in the same form, but you can pass in an hWnd to an external window and it should work the same.  You need to keep a reference to the overlay so you can close it later; this is what the second button does.  Obviously you'll have to do this differently in your application, but it's a start:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    OverlayForm overlay = null;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (overlay == null)
        {
            overlay = new OverlayForm(button2.Handle); // <-- pass in an hWnd to some external window
            overlay.Show();
        }  
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (overlay != null)
        {
            overlay.Close();
            overlay = null;
        }
    }

}

public class OverlayForm : Form
{

    private IntPtr ExternalhWnd;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT
    {
        public int Left;        // x position of upper-left corner
        public int Top;         // y position of upper-left corner
        public int Right;       // x position of lower-right corner
        public int Bottom;      // y position of lower-right corner
    }

    public OverlayForm(IntPtr ExternalhWnd)
    {
        this.ExternalhWnd = ExternalhWnd;

        this.TopMost = true;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;        
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;

        this.Opacity = 0.7; // 70% opacity
        this.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams 
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams createParams = base.CreateParams;
            createParams.ExStyle |= 0x00000020; // WS_EX_TRANSPARENT - Ignore Mouse Clicks
            createParams.ExStyle |= 0x80; // WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW - Remove from Alt-Tab List
            return createParams;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnShown(e);
        if (!this.ExternalhWnd.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            // position our overlay on top of the external window
            RECT rct;
            GetWindowRect(this.ExternalhWnd, out rct);
            this.Location = new Point(rct.Left, rct.Top);
            this.Size = new Size(rct.Right - rct.Left, rct.Bottom - rct.Top);
        }
    }

}
```

Here's a picture of the form before and after button1 is clicked:

[image]

[image]

Button2 still reacts to user input and clicks when the yellow overlay is present.

Do ask as many questions as you like to understand the code and implement it in your project.  I'll do my best to help you out...

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this. I'm going to mark this as the correct answer, as I'm a newbie, and I'll study your code and apply it! Thanks!